# Dropping shapes from multiple shape sheets using Visio VBA

Tags: vba, visio

I want to be able to drop shapes from different sheets using VBA. I can do it using the following:

```
AppVisio.Documents.AddEx "basflo_u.vst", 0, 0
AppVisio.Documents.OpenEx "basic_u.vss", visOpenRO + visOpenDocked

Do

Set currentcell = Worksheets("sheet").Range("A1")

    box_type = currentcell.Offset(0, 1)

    Select Case box_type
        Case "Process", "Start/End", "Document", "Decision", "Subprocess"
            shape_sheet = "basflo_u.vss"
        Case "Ellipse", "Square", "Rectangle", "Circle"
            shape_sheet = "basic_u.vss"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Invalid shape: " & box_type & " on line: " & currentcell.row
    End Select

    'Drop shape
    Set new_shape =  AppVisio.ActiveWindow.Page.Drop(AppVisio.Documents.Item(shape_sheet).Masters.ItemU(box_type), 2, 2)

Loop Until IsEmpty(currentcell.Offset(0, next_offset))
```

but this seems really clumsy! Do I have to know the shape sheet for every shape I drop? Is there a way to drop a shape without knowing it's shape sheet?

Using Visio 2010 Standard

Input file is:

```
Shape Text          Shape Type
Start               Start/End
Process 1           Process
If Something        Decision
Process 2           Process
Data                Ellipse   ' Note comes from different shape sheet basic_u.vss
Process 3           Process
If Something Else   Decision
Process 4           Subprocess
End                 Start/End
```

Comment: What is the reason that you work through the list to delete the items? 
Do you want to delete all shapes on the sheet?

Comment: I'm not deleting the shapes, we're drawing them on the page, but it seems that you have to know the template that the shape comes from to drop, hence the lines:   AppVisio.Documents.AddEx "basflo_u.vst", 0, 0
AppVisio.Documents.OpenEx "basic_u.vss", visOpenRO + visOpenDocked. Just seems really weird that you cannot drop any shape by name but you have to include each template.